# How do I copy/paste pose in blender 2.83

Tags: animation

I'm trying to copy paste object pose. I'm going to pose mode and copy source object pose with Ctrl+C, then I'm going to destination object, pressing Ctrl+V and Blender displays the dialog:

[image: Paste pose dialog]

Unfortunately, nothing else happens.

Please tell me how to complete the paste operation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: first, your destination bone must have the same name as the original, and secondly you must create at least one keyframe for the destination bone to be able to paste something, maybe it has to do with one of these 2 reasons?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I think I did everything like that. Could this be related to a specific version of blender?

Comment: I don't think so, maybe share your file, or at least a part that we can test: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you for your help. My file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/w6djOWBa/. It does not contain any objects, except armatures, because I use it in my research, where I need only character pose.

Comment: it seems to work, if for example I select bone-6-8 (upper arm) of Armature.001, go in the Dope Sheet, select all the keyframes, copy, then select Armature.003, and paste in the Dope Sheet, the animation is copied. You could also simply switch the Dope Sheet to Action Editor mode and select the animation you want if it's exactly the same...

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works. Indeed, I needed to use Dope Sheet, and I tried to do everything in 3D Viewport Window, which is probably why there were problems. It is a pity that this information was not in the manual.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to learn with the manual, rather follow some youtube tutorials  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select *Bone-6-8* (upper arm) of *Armature.001*, go in the *Dope Sheet*, select all the keyframes, copy, then select *Armature.003*, and paste in the *Dope Sheet*, the animation is copied. You could also simply switch the *Dope Sheet* to *Action Editor* mode and select the animation if you want to use the exact same animation.